# Shuffling in spark

Tags: apache-spark, shuffle

I need to understand how shuffling happens in Spark. Whether shuffling is performance overhead in BYKEY operations. In general for an RDD how shuffling will happen and pair RDD or joins how shuffling will happen. If you can explain with example in RDD and pair RDD it would be great.

Comment: you can through following article: https://0x0fff.com/spark-architecture-shuffle/

Answer (score 1):

Shuffling happens In ByKey Operations are an Overhead and it happens to bring a certain set of keys to be processed by a particular Worker Node.

When you perform a groupByKey() and rdd.toDebugString you will see the stages of RDD in which you will see Shuffled RDD in case of 'groupByKey'.

So for example Lets say you have 3 nodes : (Assuming data is in Pair RDD form)

```
Node 1 -> Contains -> ("California", "San Francisco"), ("Texas", "Dallas")

Node 2 -> Contains -> ("Utah", "Salt Lake City"), ("California", "San Jose")

Node 3 -> Contains -> ("Texas", "Austin"), ("Utah", "St.George")
```

Now if you perform a groupByKey on a RDD consisting this Data it will bring all similar keys under 1 node. So after Shuffling your data will look like

```
 Node 1 -> Contains -> ("California", Iterable(("San Francisco", "SanJose")))           

 Node 2 -> Contains -> ("Utah", Iterable(("Salt Lake City", "St.George")))

 Node 3 -> Contains -> ("Texas", Iterable(("Austin"), ("Dallas")))
```